# Software to find network security loopholes of Android Application

Tags: android, security, network-monitor

I am looking for a software that can check the security loopholes in Android Application. I have an Android Application and I want to check that how many network based call that application is making in background or while running. I want to find out those links. Just like the [Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) software does in the desktop-base application.

- Should be run in Win-XP System or Android Phone it self
- First Priory is free, if not then suggest me paid software.

Answer (score 2):

For network analysis of an Android app, there's a couple of ways you could go.

One option (assuming that it's HTTP traffic) would be just to use [Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) as you do for desktop applications.

Another option might be to use a dedicated Android assessment tool like [Drozer](https://www.mwrinfosecurity.com/products/drozer/) from MWR.

Comment: More details would be better - and a recommendation as to which *you* think is best would be nice too.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is kind of vague, which kind of forced the vagueness of my answer.  Drozer and Burp don't really cover the exactly the same territory. If it's software vulns in Android applications I'd recommend Drozer, if it's looking at HTTP calls from the application to a server I'd recommend Burp.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Linux LiveCD/DVD/USB.  Put a machine on the network where it can see the traffic of the android device and use wireshark, ethereal, and similar utilities.  Kali Linux has all of these and more - https://www.kali.org/